# Is Windows 10 compatible with SQL Server 2014 Developer MDS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-10, master-data-services

I have recently installed SQL Server 2014 Developer edition onto my PN, which has Windows 10 Professional installed. I upgraded from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro last year as it was a free update from Microsoft.

I am trying to install Master Data Services and I receive the following warning:

> Before creating an MDS web application, you must correct the following errors:
>   Internet Information Services (IIS) is not configured on this server.
>   These required Web Server role services are not installed:
>   Windows Authentication
>   For web application requirements, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=309491.

I am now going to install Windows authentication to correct the problem.  However, I have looked at the link and Windows 10 Pro is not listed as being compatible with SQL Server 2014 Developer edition. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is fine; the documentation was just written long before Windows 10 was released and hasn't been updated (I've sent in a note that it should be corrected).

In fact [it is listed as fully supported here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx), with no special caveats for MDS. I have never heard of any components of SQL Server 2014 having any compatibility issues with Windows 10.